# Restart download Mac OS X (macOS) Sierra, Developer Preview version

Tags: mac-appstore, preview, developer-program, macos

My download of macOS Sierra (Developer Preview, see [press release](https://www.apple.com/pr/library/2016/06/13Apple-Previews-Major-Update-with-macOS-Sierra.html)) began downloading, appearing in the Launchpad app. But then got interrupted. It failed to restart, so I deleted the icon in Launchpad by holding down Option key and clicking the "X" icon that appears.

Now when I try the download again, the link on the Developer page takes me to the App Store app. There I get page with a `Redeem` button and an error message saying “This code has already been redeemed.”.

How can I restart the download?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have already successfully redeemed your code:

- Go to the **Purchased** Tab of the Mac App Store.
- Click the **Download** button on the **10.12 Developer Preview** listing.

It is the same process as re-downloading anything from the Mac App Store.